# Finding a counterexample to a function proof

Tags: functions, proof-writing

This is my proof: If f and g are surjective, then g ◦ f is surjective, with f: A $\to$ B and g: B $\to$ C.

I have successfully proved this, but now I have to disprove the converse by finding a counterexample where A=B=C= $\mathbb{R}$.

Is a counterexample to the converse possible? If one of the functions is not surjective, then how can the composition maintain surjectivity?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Big Hint: you could find a function $B \to C$ such that only a small part of $B$ already covers whole $C$, and make sure that $A \to B$ maps onto that part. Then the composite will be surjective, but you can make $f$ not to be.

Don't try to find non-surjective $g$, since the statement $gf$ surjective implies $g$ surjective.

Comment: But how could I do that if every set is equal to the set of real numbers?

Comment: @J-Play see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

consider $g(x) = \cot(x)$ if $x\neq \frac n\pi$, $f(\pi) = 0$.
And $f(x) =\pi\cos x$.